# Access existing/old kuberenetes cluster or via kubectl command from a new machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, kubernetes, kubectl

I have already made a **cluster** which is running in **AWS cloud** with 1 master and 5 nodes. Unfortunately the computer(mac book) that I launched the cluster broke down so now I dont know how to access that old cluster with my new computer(mac book) and new **kubernetes/kubectl** environment in it.

Comment: do you have a backup of your PC? Have you saved your keys and other relevant stuff?

Comment: I have a repo which has yaml files that create deployments, services, hpa, secrets, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to ssh to the master (API server) through your AWS account credentials.

From the master, you can try a couple approaches -- see https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/ for a list of authentication methods that can be used in your cluster. Most convenient would probably be to locate the `--client-ca-file` argument that is being passed to your `kube-apiserver` process, and use that certificate authority private key to generate a new client cert.

Once you have a new client cert you can regenerate your kubeconfig using this guide: https://lukemarsden.github.io/docs/user-guide/sharing-clusters/.

This is probably going to be a bit hairy! Good luck.